# Android application dynamically switch Menu Sliding library

Tags: android, dynamic, menu, switch-statement, slide

I am in the very early stages of an Android application.

I have a primary testing device running Android 2.2.2 [FROYO] with a minimum SDK requirement of 8.
A second device runs on Android 4.0.3 [ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1] with a minimum SDK requirement of 15.

**Here's my problem, I want to implement a sliding menu in my app but I can't find a solution which will satisfy the two PLATFORM VERSIONS.**

Ice-Cream-Sandwich works with an [NavigationDrawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) implementation for a slidemenu.
I've also been researching this [SlidingMenu](http://www.michenux.net/android-sliding-menu-part-1-657.html) which will work for Froyo.

> I need to know if there is any way of setting up one Android project
>   to dynamically switch between both slide menu libraries so the project
>   will only be developed once rather than have two implementations?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's compatible with *Android 2.2*, but you could try [MenuDrawer](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer).

Answer (score 0):

The [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) used by the Navigation Drawer design document you linked to is available via the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) and supports Android 1.6 and up.

Comment: I'm new at this so I could be wrong but I downloaded the sample app which comes with a minimumSDK-Requirement of 14. I changed it to 8 and it complained i:e the app developed an error as a result

Comment: Yes, but none of those problems were due to the Navigation Drawer, but instead due to it using the native version of components like `Fragment` (which only appeared in v11) instead of their Support Library equivalents. It would probably be a great intro to the Support Library in general in converting that app to run on v8+ devices - there are many Stack Overflow answers detailing the solution to each error message you may face.